# SEO considerations when using Angular's $location to trigger view change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

My Site: [m.amsterdamfoodie.nl](http://m.amsterdamfoodie.nl).

I have implemented a set of Angular-UI radio buttons (on an off-canvas sidebar) to navigate the main subpages of my Angular site. These buttons trigger model changes, which I watch for those in the controller and use to implement `$location` changes, including changes to the URL. As a result there are no explicit hyperlinks in the page, but I want all the URLs indexed.

Although I have submitted a sitemap to Google very few pages are being indexed: none of the category subpages nor the individual restaurant pages. I was advised that, in fact, a sitemap is no substitute for the lack of a link structure. So now I'm looking for advice on the best way to create links.

Here is the HTML (with a link just added to the first button as an example of my current thinking, but I find this rather un-DRY and un-intuitive):

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified price">
    <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="main.price" btn-radio="'1'"><a href="criteria/budget/1" ng-click="event.preventDefault()">Budget</a></label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="main.price" btn-radio="'2'">Mid-range</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="main.price" btn-radio="'3'">Fine dining</label>
</div>
```

In `MainCtrl` which is loaded with `controllerAs main` I have

```
$scope.$watch 'main.price', (newVal) ->
    if newVal
        Restos.data.offcanvas = false
        $location.path '/criteria/price/'+newVal
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assume that the Google crawler will not execute JavaScript, therefore no content that is generated by JavaScript will be visible to the crawler.

A fairly common solution to SEO issues with SPA's is to use a pre-rendering service (such as [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/)) to intercept crawler requests and provide static HTML for them.

The service I linked to is a SAAS that has released their product as an open source library as well.

Comment: Google is getting better at javascript, and from the webmaster tools, it is clear that Google can read my site well, but it seems to need links. Would pre-rendering turn `$location` statements into links?